# SABRE / Acces to CreateTokenRQ

Tags: sabre

I have a problem when try to access CreateTokenRQ ,  the system reply me whit this error 
AuthorizationException: errors.authorization.USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED

I use the seme parameter that use in SOAP api CreateSession..

This is sample log:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader d3p1:version="1.0" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <d3p1:From>
                <d3p1:PartyId>tnsfrom@tns.it</d3p1:PartyId>
            </d3p1:From>
            <d3p1:To>
                <d3p1:PartyId>tnsto@tns.it</d3p1:PartyId>
            </d3p1:To>
            <d3p1:CPAId>9WDA</d3p1:CPAId>
            <d3p1:ConversationId>PROFILE</d3p1:ConversationId>
            <d3p1:Service>TokenCreateRQ</d3p1:Service>
            <d3p1:Action>TokenCreateRQ</d3p1:Action>
            <d3p1:MessageData>
                <d3p1:MessageId>mid:20170131-180233-0067+01:007261@tns.it</d3p1:MessageId>
                <d3p1:Timestamp>2017-01-31T17:02:33Z</d3p1:Timestamp>
            </d3p1:MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>USER</Username>
                <Password>PASS</Password>
                <Organization xmlns="">PCC</Organization>
                <Domain xmlns="">DEFAULT</Domain>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <TokenCreateRQ Version="1.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com"/>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">tnsto@tns.it</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">tnsfrom@tns.it</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>9WDA</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>PROFILE</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">Session</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>TokenCreateRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>5872564613545250881</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-01-31T17:02:34</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:20170131-180233-0067+01:007261@tns.it</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">T1RLAQLXzOPymarKW6vpSao+D9NVBvlbrBCF19eTo+4IS4u5yQxX3WI/AACwNl4HnFuLzWcfmUdC3MwzQfHXkHiyJUWVvYVGkM7BTH1Zk8QPN5gtUNaWLkghZY3W4zUgz77ECyxXU9sq0QC8wIRfEHyy0Wa4Gyu+F+21wVJNIwul7zAv4A0Nb+H+EhwvplAesYlVYLIsBl1G3V7sPYY6JYp8ndv468hKdzO/aR9EH19+mRxAZ5wcubk1RzQ+TSAA7ebVYg/dp9Ol8fpgzvzTkyOCnY3XuJzAdWkJLtI*</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <sws:TokenCreateRS xmlns:sws="http://webservices.sabre.com" Version="1.0.0">
            <sws:Success/>
        </sws:TokenCreateRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>tnsfrom@tns.it</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>tnsto@tns.it</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId>9WDA</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>PROFILE</ConversationId>
            <Service>TravelItineraryRead</Service>
            <Action>TravelItineraryReadRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>mid:20170131-175750-6558+01:007261@tns.it</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2017-01-31T16:57:50Z</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken>T1RLAQJImqTy22oj2jew4n0kmkJNcubdhhCo94FnWiXB3eCaPy8XKW4LAACwQPhiertpCYnV0Pnmp59O10SK93/haq3stjgk6LKovw8hLLAtptGCQMtPxN/8NJVTkite1lqWHaSkOPZdFlr8C9CkRAcKpfiDnYeC9HEuSI3IyEH54ImqhM3PIH3eD5wLo9mcDdAObuzJNJoU/k435X/+H5khEW9syHBy01kE3L23/eW1k/qdfAodQy2DDuFh2JK2tCY/s5SfcbGt9UxMBKJnrR1FbT73D4QgQYRyuEU*</BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <TravelItineraryReadRQ Version="3.4.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
            <MessagingDetails>
                <SubjectAreas>
                    <SubjectArea>FULL</SubjectArea>
                </SubjectAreas>
            </MessagingDetails>
            <UniqueID ID="DMVNRR"/>
            <ReturnOptions UnmaskCreditCard="true"/>
        </TravelItineraryReadRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">tnsto@tns.it</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">tnsfrom@tns.it</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>9WDA</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>PROFILE</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>TravelItineraryRead</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>5839433610707910872</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-01-31T16:57:50</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:20170131-175750-6558+01:007261@tns.it</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">T1RLAQJImqTy22oj2jew4n0kmkJNcubdhhCo94FnWiXB3eCaPy8XKW4LAACwQPhiertpCYnV0Pnmp59O10SK93/haq3stjgk6LKovw8hLLAtptGCQMtPxN/8NJVTkite1lqWHaSkOPZdFlr8C9CkRAcKpfiDnYeC9HEuSI3IyEH54ImqhM3PIH3eD5wLo9mcDdAObuzJNJoU/k435X/+H5khEW9syHBy01kE3L23/eW1k/qdfAodQy2DDuFh2JK2tCY/s5SfcbGt9UxMBKJnrR1FbT73D4QgQYRyuEU*</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthorizationFailed</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Authorization failed</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthorizationException: errors.authorization.USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED</StackTrace>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted obviously never worked with Sabre's "Web Services" and doesn't even understand the question. ebXML-*ish*, deprecated SOAP standards and insonsistent error messages.

Comment: This is an *USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED* message, not an authentication error. Could it be that the token service isn't activated for your PCC perhaps? Have you tried it with the test environment? Sabre returns an authorization error when you try to use a service your company hasn't bought. It can also appear if the service is activated in one PCC but not another

Answer (score 1):

The TravelItineraryReadRQ service you are looking to consume is not yet enabled for Access Tokens. This for the moment is limited to SessionToken. This is specified in the Authentication header.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Get_Itinerary